# ZeroMQ Rebuild for Electron 5.1.0 fails with error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found

Tags: npm, electron, npm-install, zeromq, failed-installation

I'm trying to install ZeroMQ into an electron application but I'm unable to rebuild the package for electron.

I'm trying to install ZeroMQ for electron 5.1.0 on my Windows 10 machine. Details:

OS: Windows 10
Electron: 5.0.8
node: 12.0.0

As per the instructions in the README.md https://github.com/zeromq/zeromq.js/, I have followed this procedure:

1) Install zeromq with npm
`npm install zeromq`

2) Rebuild for electron
`npm rebuild zeromq --runtime=electron --target=5.1.0`
Notes: The documentation indicates that the target here is supposed to be the Electron version; however, this causes a 404 error as npm tries to go to https://nodejs.org/dist/v5.0.8/node-v5.0.8-headers.tar.gz which doesn't exist. I then thought to try the node version, but that leads to a 401 error. I then tried the zeromq version (5.1.0 as shown in command) which leads to this error:

`error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.`

Googling this error brings up a lot of StackOverflow problems where the build tools are required. Looking a little ahead on the README.md led me to thing I could solve this problem using the next command.

3) Install visual studio build tools
`npm install --global --production windows-build-tools`
This command is completed successfully and installs both the build tools and python2.7

4) Rerunning the rebuild command in step 2 leads to the same error. I tried variations of this command:
`npm config set msvs_version 2013`
using 2015 and 2017 as well.

2013 and 2015 give this error:
`error MSB4019: The imported project "C:\Microsoft.Cpp.Default.props" was not found. Confirm that the path in the <Import> declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.
gyp ERR! build error
gyp ERR! stack Error: C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\msbuild.exe failed with exit code: 1
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.onExit (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\build.js:262:23)
gyp ERR! stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:198:13)
gyp ERR! stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:248:12)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\<user>\path\to\app\node_modules\zeromq
gyp ERR! node -v v10.16.0
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.8.0
gyp ERR! not ok
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! zeromq@5.1.0 install: node scripts/prebuild-install.js || (node scripts/preinstall.js && node-gyp rebuild)
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the zeromq@5.1.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.`

While 2017 gives this:
`error MSB8020: The build tools for v140 (Platform Toolset = 'v140') cannot be found. To build using the v140 bui
ld tools, please install v140 build tools.  Alternatively, you may upgrade to the current Visual Studio tools by select
ing the Project menu or right-click the solution, and then selecting "Retarget solution". [C:\Users\<user>\path\to\app\node_modules\zeromq\build\zmq.vcxproj]`
with a similar ending section as the other years produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end this was a visual studio build tools install error. I uninstalled visual studio using the visual studio installer and then reinstalled windows-build-tools.